# How do I create a PGP Key Revocation Certificate in Kleopatra

Tags: windows, pgp, macos

I was successfully able to create a PGP Key using Seahorse in Ubuntu's Passwords and Keys (13.04). I was also able to create a revocation certificate, if needed in the future, using the terminal in Ubuntu.

My problem concerns doing this on a Windows machine (*and Mac*). I downloaded **[Gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/download.html)** and used Kleopatra to create a PGP Key. I am however unable to find a way to create a revocation certificate for the key I generated.

I would appreciate some direction with this issue.

Comment: You can create a certificate using the same commands like you did in Ubuntu - all you might have is add `gpg.exe` to your path variable or use the full path of the executable. If you're using the same key on both machines, you can copy the revocation certificate; it will be the same anyway.

Comment: Thank you Jens. Please pardon my newbieness, but I don't know the click path in Windows to get the "Terminal" window. Do I just run command prompt and enter `gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke mykey`?

Comment: Yes, the terminal is called command prompt in windows. You can type `gpg ...` if `gpg.exe` is in your path, otherwise you'll have to call it using `C:\Program Files\...\gpg.exe ...` (fit to your install directory). You will realize that you've got to do this when executing `gpg` fails.

Comment: Thank you Jens. `gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke mykey` worked. Adding it in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under current versions of gpg4win, you can simply select the key, then open the "View" menu and select "Details".

[image: View Details Menu]

Then use the "Generate revocation certificate" button.

[image: Details Window]

Comment: Would you have a screenshot to share by chance? I'd be happy to make yours the accepted answer. Merci.

Comment: Then what? This answer seems incomplete.  After clicking the "Generate revocation certificate" option Additional prompts appear.

Answer (score 15):

*Slightly modified [**answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/323309/60869) by Jens Erat on Ask Ubuntu, plus information from comments above*.

--

If you're fine with using the command line, this is easily done using [`gpg --gen-revoke`](http://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/c14.html#REVOCATION) using Windows Command Prompt.

On Windows, if you do not change anything else, the revocation certificate is stored in `revoke.asc` in your home directory (C:\Users\Name), and you should replace `mykey` by your key id.

```
gpg --output revoke.asc --gen-revoke mykey
```

Remember to store it in a safe place, for example by printing it to a QR code or something similar.

Just in case if you're wondering on how to get the keyID of a key in the Command Prompt, (I ran into this :), It's the last 8 characters of your public key, which you could easily get printed by using the following commands.

```
gpg --fingerprint
```

OR

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Answer (score 9):

In Kleopatra, right-click on your key and click on *Details*.  There will be a button called *Generate revocation certificate*.

Comment: This seems to be an incomplete answer as well.  There are additional steps after Generate revocation certificate.